# Docker останавливается сразу после запуска демон-процесса

Tags: python, docker

У меня небольшой `Gunicorn` сервис. Вот мой `Dockerfile` для него:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get clean && apt-get update && apt-get install -y locales
RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
RUN update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_MESSAGES=POSIX

RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get -y upgrade \
&& apt-get install -y python-pip \
&& mkdir /app


ADD . app
WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["/usr/local/bin/gunicorn", "--config", "/app/gunicorn.py", "myrun:app", "&&", "tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
The problem is I can't hold the container as the active process. I run it so: docker run --name pypypy -td -p 8187:8081 pytest.
```

После запуска докер возвращает мне `id` контейнера и не выдает никаких ошибок. Но потом можно найти запущенный процесс процесс только через `docker ps -a`. Что я делаю не так ? Смотрел [некоторый посты](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30209776/docker-container-will-automatically-stop-after-docker-run-d) на stackoverflow, но это не работает в моем случае. Почему ?

Comment: Ну я так понимаю он вам создает контейнер. А запускать его вроде как нужно (не силён сам сильно в докере)

Comment: `tail -f /dev/null` - очень интересная конструкция:)  после запуска подключится к порту 8187 получается?

Comment: Если у вас контейнер виден в выводе docker ps, значит он запущен и работает. Покажите `netstat -t4lpn` на хосте с докером. И да, выше это docker build или всё-же docker run

Answer (score 2):

> Что я делаю не так ?

Мешаете аргументы и shell-конструкции

```
CMD ["/usr/local/bin/gunicorn", "--config", "/app/gunicorn.py", "myrun:app", "&&", "tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
```

здесь && - это строковый аргумент, а не конструкция AND

> После запуска докер возвращает мне id контейнера и не выдает никаких ошибок. Но потом можно найти запущенный процесс процесс только через docker ps -a

В `ps -a` и будет ваша ошибка, точне, exit code. `docker logs <container-id>` выдаст вам все, что ушло в stdout. Судя по тому, что вы пытаетесь запустить tail вслед за gunicorn, последний по умолчанию запускает демон и выходит, и вам на самом деле надо просто найти ключ, который запустит его как обычное приложение (в foreground).